# I can't retrieve my Facebook password

Tags: facebook, facebook-account

I haven't been to my Facebook account in a while and I can't remember my password. When I try to have it reset, it goes to a security question, but I can't remember that either.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2):

According to the official "[I can’t remember the answer to my security question](https://www.facebook.com/help/189150081132128)" Facebook help page:

> If you're trying to get back into your account and you can't answer
>   your security question, you may have the option to [**get help from
>   friends**](https://www.facebook.com/help/215543298568604).

If you don't have access to the email address you used to create your profile, [see the rest of their official answer](https://www.facebook.com/help/189150081132128).

Answer (score 2):

**I can’t reset my password because I can't access the email address listed on my account.**

You may be able to get back into your Facebook account by answering a security question, using an alternate email address listed on your account or [getting help from friends](https://www.facebook.com/help/215543298568604). Keep in mind that you'll only see these options if you set them up.

To see if you have these options:

1. Go to the Facebook login page and click [Forgot your password? or Can't login?](https://www.facebook.com/login/identify) in the top right.
2. Fill out the form to identify your account.
3. Select **I forgot my password** on the next page if prompted.
4. Look at the list of email addresses listed on your account. If you don't have access to any of these, click **No longer have access to these?**
5. Follow the directions provided to answer your security question or get help from friends, if you see these options, or contact your email service provider.

Once you get back into your account you can change your login email address at any time from your [account settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings). You can also log into Facebook with any email address you've added to your account.

<sub>Source: https://www.facebook.com/help/132243923516844</sub>